# Float right no coloca div a la derecha del contenedor

Tags: html, css

Tengo este código HTML y CSS:

```
<body>
        <header class="Header">
            <div class="Header__Buttons">
                <a href="" class="Link">Sign up</a>
                <button type="button" class="Button">Sign in</button>
            </div>
        </header>        
</body>
```

```
.Header
    height: 70px
    padding: 0 100px
    box-sizing: border-box
    display: flex

.Header__Buttons 
    float: right
```

El Header tiene un width de 100vw, y quiero colocar el div class Header__Buttons al final a la derecha del div. No quiero usar flex, quiero usar float.

Comment: Si usas flexbox, los float no sirven, usa justify-content: flex-end

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar este código:

```
 <header class="Header">
   <div class="Header__Buttons">
       <a href="" class="Link">Sign up</a>
       <button type="button" class="Button">Sign in</button>
   </div>
</header>
```

```
.Header{
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0 100px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
}

.Header__Buttons{ 
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px; 
    top: 10px;
}
```